# Ionic3 lazy loading and translate don't work together

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Recently I upgraded the Ionic and now its Ionic3

Now the current application does not work with Ionic and ng2-translate altogether.

The same code was working fine earlier without lazy loading, but we need to use lazy loading as to improve application loading time and reduce splash shown duration.

The app.module.ts import component looks like

```
TranslateModule.forRoot({
provide: TranslateLoader,
useClass: TMATranslationLoader
})
```

TMATranslationLoader looks like

```
export class TMATranslationLoader implements TranslateLoader {
  constructor(  ) { }

  getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
    switch(lang) {
      case 'nl':
        return Observable.of(translations_nl);
      case 'hi':
        return Observable.of(translations_hi);
      // case 'de':
      //   return Observable.of(translations_de);
      // case 'fr':
      //   return Observable.of(translations_fr);
      // case 'es':
      //   return Observable.of(translations_es);
      default:
        return Observable.of(translations_en);
    }
  }
}
```

app.component.ts looks like

```
this.rootPage = 'LoginPage';
```

login-page.html looks like

```
<ion-label floating>{{ 'LBL_USERNAME' | translate }}</ion-label>
```

The run time exception which is trown

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'translate' could not be found (" <ion-list>
<ion-item class="icon-user">
<ion-label floating>{{ [ERROR ->]'LBL_USERNAME' | translate }}</ion-label>
```

Any idea? Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since lazy load pages include their own module, now you need to import the translate module in every *lazy load page's module* where it's going to be used.

Please take a look at [ionic docs related to this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/ng2-translate/#lazy-loading-pages). Like you can see there, the steps to use ngx-translate are:

1) **Installing**

To install ngx-translate run

```
npm install @ngx-translate/core @ngx-translate/http-loader --save.
```

2) **Bootstrapping**

To use ngx-translate, it must first be imported and added to the imports array **in the NgModule of the application**.

```
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
...

export function createTranslateLoader(http: Http) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
        deps: [Http]
      }
    })
  ]
})
```

3) **Lazy loading pages**

If you want to use Ionics lazy loading pages together with `ngx-translate`, you have to configure your `component.module.ts` files

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { HelloPage } from './hello-page';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HelloPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(HelloPage),
    TranslateModule.forChild()
  ],
  exports: [
    HelloPage
  ]
})
export class HelloPageModule {}
```

Comment: Is there any way that we can use ng2-translate and lazy loading. The ngx-translate works well. Else, I need to update ng2-translate to ngx-translate.

Comment: I wouldn't know for sure since I started using `ngx-translate` directly, I'm sorry.. But glad to see that it still helped :)

Comment: I successfully updated the ng2-translate to ngx-translate. The only difference (for methods) is ng2-translate does not have forChild() in TranslateModule. Its only having forRoot(). In ngx-translate is having both forRoot() and forChild(). Thanks for your support.

Comment: Np at all, glad to hear that the solution worked on your end :)

Comment: I get this error: `Could not find IonicModule.forRoot call in "imports"`. Do I need to keep `forRoot` and `forChild`? This is not clear on the documentation

Comment: @Dani User forRoot as forChild is not available